# Restrict access to custom post type based on its taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, user-roles, capabilities

I'm just beginning to understand the roles and capabilities in Wordpress and I'm not sure that I can do what I would like.

I have a custom post type, "cats", that has specific taxonomies such as "status", "age", "breed"...
And I have a custom role, "gallerist".

I would like the gallerists to be able to create, edit, delete and manage only the "cats" posts that have a specific taxonomy term assigned to them. For example the gallerists would be able to edit the cats posts where "age" is "kitten" but not the cats where "age" is "adult".

Is it possible?

Comment: I would to the following: use add_cap to add a custom capability to gallerist, for example "can_edit_kittens". Then on edit (for example save_post action) check if the user has this capability using current_user_can().

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the conditions and add capabilities like this:

```
if(wp_get_current_user('gallerist') AND 
  'cats' == get_post_type() AND 
  has_term( 'status', 'age' )) {  

$gallerist_role = get_role( 'gallerist' );

// Adding a new capability to role
$gallerist_role->add_cap( 'custom_capability' );
}
```

I am sorry I can not test it but I think it is a start